# Upper bounds for largest element in the kth column in Gaussian elimination

Tags: inequality, induction, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I am struggle with this exercise in numerical analysis topic.

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ nonsingular matrix and $A^{(k)}$ the matrix obtained in the $k$-th step of Gaussian elimination for $A$ with $A^{(0)}=A$.
Let $A^{(k)}=(a^{(k)}_{r,s})$

and $a_k=\max_{r,s}|a^{k}_{r,s}|$.

Suppose that partial pivoting is used in the elimination. Show that:

a) $a_{k}\leq 2^{k}a_{0}$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$ for arbitrary $A$, and

b) $a_{k}\leq 2-a_{0}$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$ for tridiagonal matrices $A$.

I would appreciate any hint for right direction to start. I found [this](http://www.math.clemson.edu/%7Ehklee/mthsc460/note2.pdf) notation convenient.

Many thanks